# After insert trigger works but no effect on the target table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Orders` which has information about each order placed by the customers. For testing purpose i created a table called `OrderCountTable` which count how many order was placed by each customer. to update this table i created after insert trigger on `Orders` table so that after inserting a record in the table the trigger will update the orders count in `OrderCountTable` for the customer or create a new record for the customer if it is the first order. when i insert a new record into `Orders` table, from the output it seems the trigger was fired but when i check `OrderCountTable` it is always empty, did i miss something??

```
CREATE TABLE OrderCountTable(
CustomerID int,
OrderCount int);
Go 
CREATE TRIGGER CustomerOrderCount
ON Orders
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CUID as int = (select CustomerID from inserted);
    IF((select COUNT(CustomerID) from OrderCountTable where CustomerID = @CUID) IS NULL)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO OrderCountTable VALUES(@CUID,1);
            Print 'New record was inserted for ' + CONVERT(varchar,@CUID);
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE OrderCountTable SET OrderCount = OrderCount + 1;
            Print 'Update the record for the customer with ID ' + CAST(@CUID as varchar);
        END
END
```

-- INSERTING NEW RECORD:

```
INSERT INTO Orders(ProductID,CustomerID,Quantity,OrderDate,[Status]) VALUES(1,3,4,'2022-04-3 16:22:53','OPENED');
```

-- OUTPUT:

```
(0 rows affected)
Update the record for the customer with ID 3

(1 row affected)

Completion time: 2022-04-03T16:53:54.6452596+03:00
```

-- CHECKING BOTH TABLES:

```
OrderID ProductID   CustomerID  Quantity    OrderDate   Status
17  1   3   4   2022-04-03 16:22:53 OPENED

CustomerID  OrderCount
```

Comment: Your trigger is flawed, it *assumes*  an `INSERT` can only ever contain 1 row; this is not true. If you `INSERT` 2 or more rows you will get an error.

Comment: Also your `IF` doesn't make sense; `COUNT` *can't* return `NULL`. If no rows are found in a `COUNT` then `0` is returned. As such, your `IF` will never be true.

Comment: thx Larnu. indeed, after altering the condition of the trigger to be "select COUNT(CustomerID) from OrderCountTable where CustomerID = @CUID) = 0", it worked!

Comment: ...until you add two orders at the same time, also `IF EXISTS` is much better than `COUNT` when you don't truly care about the count. Performance-wise, when the answer can only be one or zero, it may not be material; but [it's just better practice to always follow](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/10/t-sql-queries/bad-habits-count-the-hard-way#exist).

Comment: That alone does *not* fix your trigger, @MoeKronz . The `IF` was just one problem which actually shouldnt even be there, as it's part of the incorrect assumption. DML statements affect 0+ rows, not 1 row.

Comment: Do orders never get deleted? Do customers never get deleted? The view suggestion will always be correct - think about that. And consider how often one really needs to know the count of orders for any given customer.

Comment: You could use a materialised view instead, then you have no need for a trigger

Comment: @SteveFord That was one option I suggested but the bigger question I think is whether the counts need to be materialized at all (and usually the answer is no).

Answer (score 5):

Your trigger body should be:

```
UPDATE oct SET OrderCount += 1
  FROM dbo.OrderCountTable AS oct
  INNER JOIN inserted AS i
  ON i.CustomerID = oct.CustomerID;

INSERT dbo.OrderCountTable(CustomerID, OrderCount)
  SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*)
    FROM inserted AS i
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.OrderCountTable AS oct
        WHERE oct.CustomerID = i.CustomerID
    );
```

You should never rely on assigning a single value from `inserted` or `deleted` to a variable because, unlike other platforms, SQL Server only fires a trigger once even if the DML operation affected multiple rows. This strategy may seem to "work" but in the case of a multi-row operation, the variable is only assigned a single, arbitrary value and later operations will ignore all the other affected rows. Which is only "successful" because it passes some unit test and/or there is no exception - and people fail to check that the trigger's actions worked correctly against all target rows. [This presentation from several years ago could be worth a watch](https://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event14/Five_Ways_to_Write_More_Effective_Triggers).

Maybe you have them and didn't mention it, or nothing ever gets deleted, but as SMor points out you also need triggers with logic to decrement the count in this second table when an order is deleted (or remove the row entirely when a customer is deleted), or to combine rows when two customers are merged or the Orders.CustomerID is updated for some other reason.

Or you could consider not storing this information anywhere, because you can always get it from `Orders` without the need for a second table or a trigger at all:

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM dbo.Orders
  GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

You could also create an indexed view to replace your table (and also eliminate any need for a trigger):

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.RedundantOrderCount
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT CustomerID, OrderCount = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.Orders
    GROUP BY CustomerID;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CIX_RedundantOrderCount
  ON dbo.RedundantOrderCount(CustomerID);
```

This also automatically handles the situation where orders are updated or deleted. But it's still potentially wasteful to maintain that view unless there is so much activity that the direct query gets too expensive *and* you are running the query more often than you are updating the table, which is unlikely.

Premature optimization (which is what you're doing by redundantly storing aggregates to avoid calculating them later) seems fun and useful, but usually it's a waste and has an overall negative effect on your overall workload. Having a slightly faster query - at least in theory - to retrieve the counts often makes you overlook how much harder the write side of your workload has to work. It should not be ignored.